# Ограничить количество записей в БД

Tags: python, django

Как в джанго можно ограничить количество записей, которые могут быть в базе данных? Чтобы, к примеру, если количество записей максимальное, через админку (именно через неё) нельзя было добавить ещё записи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class SomeModel:
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if SomeModel.objects.count() < settings.MAX_SOMEMODEL_COUNT:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        raise ValidationError('Слишком много записей типа SomeModel!')
```

Comment: Manager isn't accessible via ShortInfoAboutCompany instances - Вот такая штука происходит

Comment: Исправил. А так?

Comment: Сработало. Спасибо большое :)